# React Native component loose arrangement when a new component is added

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have the following view in a React Native app:

[image]

And this is the code for it:
index.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Headline, Button, IconButton} from 'react-native-paper';
import ShoppingCartEntry from './ShoppingCartEntry';
import ShoppingCartContext from '../../context/shoppingCart/shoppingCartContext';

const ShoppingCartList = () => {
  const {shoppingCart} = useContext(ShoppingCartContext);

  const TotalPriceDisplay = () => {
    let totalPrice = 0;

    shoppingCart.map((entry) => {
      totalPrice = totalPrice + (entry.product.price * entry.amount);
    })

    return (
      <Headline>Total: {totalPrice}</Headline>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.cartContainer}>
      <View style={styles.icon}>
        <IconButton icon='cart' color='black' size={40}/>
      </View>
      {shoppingCart.map((entry) => {
        return (
          <ShoppingCartEntry entry={entry} />
        )
      })}
      <View style={styles.totalPrice}>
        <TotalPriceDisplay />
        <Button mode='contained'>
          Comprar
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cartContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  totalPrice: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  icon: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})

export default ShoppingCartList;
```

ShoppingCartEntry.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Headline, IconButton, Text} from 'react-native-paper';
import ShoppingCartContext from '../../context/shoppingCart/shoppingCartContext';

const ShoppingCartEntry = ({entry}) => {
  const {shoppingCartAppendProduct, shoppingCartUpdateProduct, shoppingCartRemoveProduct} = useContext(ShoppingCartContext);
  
  const removeProduct = () => {
    shoppingCartRemoveProduct(entry.product.id);
  }

  const Counter = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.counterContainer}>
        <View style={styles.counter}>
          <IconButton icon='plus' color='black' onPress={removeProduct} />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Headline color='blue'>{entry.amount}</Headline>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.counter}>
          <IconButton icon='minus' color='black' onPress={removeProduct} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.entryContainer}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <IconButton icon='delete' color='red' onPress={removeProduct} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.name}>
        <Headline>{entry.product.name}</Headline>
        <Text>{entry.product.price}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.amount}> 
        <Counter />
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{entry.product.price * entry.amount}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  entryContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingBottom: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20
  },
  name: {
    flex: 0.5
  },
  amount: {
    flex: 0.3
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flex: 0.1
  },
  counterContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  counter: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
})

export default ShoppingCartEntry;
```

The problem is that when an element is removed from `shoppingCart` and the whole view is re rendered, it looses all its formatting:

[image]

I discovered that all I have to do is to change the `StyleSheet.flexDirection` for the container from `row` to `column` and, then, back to `row` again, and the view gets arranged again, but now with the new data.

I don't know if this is a development stage issue that I shouldn't care about for production, or if there is something I can do to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `flex:1` to your base container styles for both your list and your item.

```
...    
entryContainer: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingBottom: 20,
        paddingLeft: 20
      },
...


 cartContainer: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'column', 
  },
```

Comment: Nope, I made the changes and the same